# EVT_CHAR never calls handler

Tags: python, wxwidgets, wxpython

I am continuing to have immense trouble receiving EVT_CHAR events on my custom control. After searching the internet for days, I am at a loss as to why I am not getting the events.

I understand that questions pertaining to EVT_CHAR are plenty - I have read through quite a number of them, however none of the solutions provided seem to work. I have ensured the following:

- The custom control has focus
- I am binding directly on the source of the event (the custom control)
- My custom control has wx.WANTS_CHARS. I have tried removing it, with no perceivable difference.

I have tried with and without wx.WANTS_CHARS on the frame.
I have tried binding to the frame and the control, both with and without the source parameter pointing to each.
There are no other keyboard-related event bindings, however I *do* have accelerators configured, as per the code below.

I have also tried to extend upon `wx.TextEntry`. One possibility I was attempting to chase down is that the custom control will not receive these events as it does not appear to be a text entry control, and that the event only fires on non-readonly/editable controls. I had no luck figuring this out.

**Version Information:**
I am testing this on both Python 3.7, and most often on 3.6.
wxPython version 4.0.3
Windows 10.1709 Enterprise

The following is the code snippets from my frame class, responsible for constructing the GUI and listening on these events. I have also included the (currently useless) event handler for EVT_CHAR.

```
def do_create_gui(self):
    classname = self.__class__.__name__

    app = wx.App()
    AppTitle = "%s: %s" % (self._comms.port, classname)
    size = wx.Size(700, 450)
    frame = wx.Frame(None, title=AppTitle, size=size)
    panel = wx.Panel(frame)
    panelSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

    # Configure Menu
    fileMenu = wx.Menu()
    copyitem = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_COPY, "&Copy\tCtrl-C")
    pasteitem = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_PASTE, "&Paste\tCtrl-V")
    fileMenu.AppendSeparator()
    brkitem = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, "&Break\tCtrl-B")
    fileMenu.AppendSeparator()
    quititem = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, "&Quit")

    helpMenu = wx.Menu()
    hotkeyitem = helpMenu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, "Program &Shortcuts")

    menubar = wx.MenuBar()
    menubar.Append(fileMenu, '&File')
    menubar.Append(helpMenu, '&Help')
    frame.SetMenuBar(menubar)

    self._terminal = TerminalCtrl(panel)
    self._terminal.SetSpacing(0)
    self._terminal.SetWrap(True)

    sizer.Add(self._terminal, 1, wx.EXPAND)
    panelSizer.Add(panel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
    panel.SetSizer(sizer)
    frame.SetSizer(panelSizer)
    frame.SetMinSize(wx.Size(313, 260))
    frame.Show()

    # Set up accelerators
    accelC = wx.AcceleratorEntry(wx.ACCEL_CTRL, ord('C'), wx.ID_COPY)
    accelV = wx.AcceleratorEntry(wx.ACCEL_CTRL, ord('V'), wx.ID_PASTE)
    accelB = wx.AcceleratorEntry(wx.ACCEL_CTRL, ord('B'), brkitem.GetId())
    accel = wx.AcceleratorTable([accelC, accelV, accelB])
    frame.SetAcceleratorTable(accel)

    # Bind on window events
    frame.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.onClose)
    self._terminal.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, self.onChar)

    # Bind Menu handlers
    frame.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onClose, quititem)
    frame.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.showHotkeys, hotkeyitem)
    frame.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, lambda e: self.onCopy(), copyitem)
    frame.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, lambda e: self.onPaste(), pasteitem)
    frame.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, lambda e: self.send_break(), brkitem)

    # Register for events from Serial Communications thread
    EVT_SERIAL(frame, self.onSerialData)

    # Ensure the terminal has focus
    self._terminal.SetFocus()

    self._wxObj = frame
    self._tLock.release()
    app.MainLoop()

def onChar(self, event):
    code = event.GetUnicodeKey()

    if code == wx.WXK_NONE:
        code = event.GetKeyCode()

    if (not 27 < code < 256) or event.HasAnyModifiers():
        # So we don't consume the event
        print('We don\'t process your kind here! (%d)' % code)
        event.Skip()
        return

    print("CHAR: %s(%d)" % (chr(code), code))
```

In regards to the custom control, here is the definition.

```
import wx
from wx.lib.scrolledpanel import ScrolledPanel

class TerminalCtrl(ScrolledPanel, wx.Window):
    def __init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, pos=wx.DefaultPosition,
                 size=wx.DefaultSize, style=wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL,
                 name=wx.ControlNameStr):
        pass
    pass
```

Comment: can you try the basic control and not a custom one?

Comment: Igor, there is no equivalent basic control for what I'm doing

Comment: did you do a `SetFocus()` to your custom control? If not - you can try.

Comment: If you are still getting nowhere with this, you will have to edit the above and provide an `mcve`. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks for that Rolf of Saxony, I have just figured it out with the help of Paul Cornelius below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was trying to do a similar thing and it wasn't working for me either.

Based on my experimentation, the problem is caused by the TAB_TRAVERSAL flag.  If your window is created with this flag, the TAB_TRAVERSAL mechanism appears to suck in all the EVT_CHAR events and your handler never gets called.  That's probably a bug but I'm not sure.

This flag sometimes gets set by default: for wx.Panel this is the default window style, but for wx.Window it isn't.  In my test program, when I tried to get keypresses in a Panel it didn't work, but it did if I used a wx.Window.  When I changed the style parameter for Panel to avoid setting the TAB_TRAVERSAL flag, that also worked.

I also experimented with handling the EVT_CHAR_HOOK event, and calling event.DoAllowNextEvent().  The documentation (and I use the term advisedly) says this is necessary but apparently it's not.

Here is a version of my test program that actually works.  By experimenting with it you can (sort-of) figure out what's going on.  Commenting in and out various options or changing from wx.Panel to wx.Window was very enlightening.

```
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(None, title="Char test")
        self.label = wx.StaticText(self, label="Label")
        self.panel = DaPanel(self)
        bs = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        bs.Add(self.label, wx.SizerFlags().Expand())
        bs.Add(self.panel, wx.SizerFlags(1).Expand())
        self.SetSizerAndFit(bs)
        self.SetAutoLayout(True)
        self.SetSize(wx.Size(800, 600))
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

        # self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR_HOOK, self.do_char_hook)

    def do_char_hook(self, event):
        # The functions DoAllowNextEvent and Skip seem to do the same thing
        event.DoAllowNextEvent()
        event.Skip()
        # Calling either causes the EVT_KEY_DOWN event to occur for default
        # wxPanel but make no difference for wxWindows.

class DaPanel(wx.Window):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        # default style wxPanel won't ever get EVT_CHAR events
        # default style wxWindow will get EVT_CHARs
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, self.do_char)
        # self.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.do_down)

    def do_char(self, event):
        print("char", event.GetUnicodeKey())

    def do_down(self, event):
        print("down", event.GetUnicodeKey(), self.HasFocus())
        # if you run this handler you must Skip()
        # or else no char event ever happens
        event.Skip()

def main():
    app = wx.App()
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()

main()
```

Comment: Hmm... Interesting. This claim is also supported by the documentation - see here: https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Panel.html#events-events-emitted-by-this-class I didn't notice that.

Comment: This was definitely the issue. My custom control had a default style containing TAB_TRAVERSAL. Upon removing it, the hook worked immediately - thank you very much!

Comment: I did eventually see the doc page you mentioned and that's what put me onto the solution.  I think the sentence "if not all characters are being intercepted by your OnKeyDown or OnChar handler, it may be because you are using the TAB_TRAVERSAL style, which grabs some keypresses for use by child controls" is poorly worded.  It should be "Do not use the TAB_TRAVERSAL style if you want to receive EVT_CHAR events."

Comment: I imagine that this is a bug, and only the TAB character should be the one missing, I would think it should still forward all other events - might see if this is actually a bug or an 'intended feature'.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't get `wxEVT_CHAR` for the focused window, it means that something is handling `wxEVT_KEY_DOWN` and not skipping it. This doesn't seem to happen anywhere in your code, so my only guess is that it's done by the `ScrolledPanel` class you use. Try using a plain `wxWindow` and you really should be getting the events.

Comment: Quite an interesting thought - I tried this. I removed all scrolling code, however I am still not receiving these events.

Comment: I really don't know what's going on then, there must be something you're not showing us because the code, as written, really ought to work.

Comment: Thanks for your help - it was the TAB_TRAVERSAL style

Comment: This is weird, `TAB_TRAVERSAL` can account for not getting TAB/cursor arrows, but I understood that you were not getting _any_ char events? If so, I don't see how could it be due to this...

Comment: I guess that upon setting the style, the control listens onKeyDown or onChar and doesn't skip or allow the next event? It was definitely blocking all characters, might be a bug. Either way, it is documented as the third note here: https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Panel.html#events-events-emitted-by-this-class